# Azure HDInsight authentication failure when connecting to HDInsight web portal

Tags: authentication, azure, cluster-computing, azure-hdinsight

After creating a new HDInsight Cluster, I am receiving the following error when I provide the authentication information and try to access the HDInsight web portal at https://{Cluster Name}.azurehdinsight.net/

403 - Forbidden: Access is denied.

Have tried recreating clusters, different browsers, clearing browser cache but have not been able to login.  Pls suggest.

Comment: Same issue - used a different browser and was able to login.

Answer (score 2):

The interactive console has been discontinued and the team now recommends the usage of Windows Azure PowerShell

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-submit-hadoop-jobs-programmatically/

Answer (score 1):

You mention clearing browser cache, have you also tried clearing cookies as well? I have had this problem after a failed login to the HDInsight portal and needed to clear cookies and cache.

Also if you have an active directory integration and are trying to login with a domain account, try logging in with the cluster user that you created at deployment instead.

Answer (score 0):

Use windows azure management portal instead, https://manage.windowsazure.com.

Comment: The link you have shared is for the Azure (Management) Portal.  I am trying to access the HDInsight portal, to access the HDInsight Javascript Interactive Console